# ¿Cómo levantar una alerta cuando termine el proceso del submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito una alerta cuando termine el `submit` de un formulario, el problema es que cuando le doy `click` al botón de enviar automáticamente me levanta la alerta no al finalizar el `submit` digamos.

Esto llevo hasta ahora

```
$( ".webform-client-form-197" ).submit(function( event ) {
  //alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  $('.webform-client-form-197').attr('action', '');
});
```

Comment: El submit siempre carga la pagina, a lo mejor lo que te conviene es hacer un request ajax con un callback. En jquery el submit no tiene un callback sino un handler.

Comment: crees que me serviría el handler?

Comment: Creo que deberias usar un llamado ajax en lugar de un submit

Answer (score 1):

intenta implementar una promesa.
Ejemplo[jquey promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```
 $( "div" ).promise().done(function() {
    $( "p" ).append( " Finished! " );
  });
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se usarían las promesas en este caso particular de un formulario?